# Semantic UI React- button size has no impact on size

Tags: reactjs, button, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to incorporate Semantic-UI into my site due to some apparent limitations with react-strap. However, I've run into an issue. The content width is fixed, and therefore the rightmost button is getting slightly truncated.

I tried resizing per the docs:

```
  <div>
    <Button size='mini'>Mini</Button>
    <Button size='tiny'>Tiny</Button>
    <Button size='small'>Small</Button>
    <Button size='medium'>Medium</Button>
    <Button size='large'>Large</Button>
    <Button size='big'>Big</Button>
    <Button size='huge'>Huge</Button>
    <Button size='massive'>Massive</Button>
  </div>
```

But nothing seems to make a difference here the code:

```
<Button.Group>
    <Button class="tiny ui button" positive as={Link} to={"/licenses/" + license.id}>Edit</Button>
    <Button class="tiny ui button" color='blue' onClick={() => this.download(license.url)}>Download</Button>
    <Button class="tiny ui button"  negative onClick={() => this.remove(license.id)}>xDelete</Button>
  </Button.Group>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same attribute as per the docs - instead of giving your buttons a `class` of tiny, it should be a `size` of tiny.